# How to create a custom years for DateTime in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a game where each month is 28 days, each year has 4 months.
I can't seem to find a way to modify the length of months and years.

It seems it might be possible to make your own Calendar, though I'm not sure how to approach this either.

Comment: You'll have to implement a custom `DateTime`-like type. You may want to have a look at [the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,df6b1eba7461813b) for inspiration

Comment: Jessen is right! You have to use this implementation and with it, you can enter your own days per year, days per month, etc. It's a litte bit of work, but you must only implement the methods you need. For example, only one constructor and so on..

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can use DateTime in custom ranges. But off the top of my head you could build a counter for the number of days, months and years, each time the days counter reaches 28, reset it and add to the month counter, same with the year when the month counter reaches 4.

You could use a trigger to progress the days, such as each time the player goes to sleep or use a timer that ticks, let's say every 1000 MS, for each tick increase your counter by 1.

Sorta like so:

```
public void Ticker()
   {
         System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(); 
         aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
         aTimer.Interval = 1000;
         aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (days < 28)
            days++;
        else
            days = 0;
        if (days == 28 && months < 4)
            months++;
        else if (days == 28 && months == 4)
        {
            months = 0;
            years++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: dont you mean less than? also if you, in case days became 28, reset days to zero before the 2nd if, it will never equate to true.

Comment: i btw think it would be easier to just count total days and use modulo and division to get months and years. like `day = totalDays % daysPerMonth` and so on ... the advantage would be that you can calculate fe. a timespan easily.

Comment: That's a good point, it would be much harder to find an exact time span with my method.